# Magento attribute values saved in admin disappear

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I had set up the catalog to sort on these values, which I saved through the admin last night. For most of a full day they were there. Now, like ghosts they have disappeared.

I suspect the problem could be tied to values saved through the admin rather than imported.

Can anyone point me to the source of this problem and the solution in the code?

Between the last time I saw the values working on the frontend (a few hours ago) and now, I did several things:

1.) Added 2 new attributes and some test values (unrelated to problem attribute), reindexed.

2.) Tried to import unrelated values for 60,000 products. Import hanged, so

3.) Imported values for 20,000 products at a time, no errors.

4.) reindexed.

Now all values saved manually are gone. Again, how can this happen? If they were saved to the DB, then shouldn't it take an delete call from the code to the DB to do this? How/why would such a call be made when I did not execute any such command in code or through admin? How can I fix this and avaoid in future?

TO AXEL (clarifying):

Thanks for your reply, @Axel.

1.) I created a **text attribute** called "**sort_order**" and entered some integer values through the **admin**.

2.) Then I did a **full db backup** with mysqldump.

3.) Then, I created two new attributes, "**random_order**" (**price** type) and "**random_order_1**" (**text** type). The purpose was to experiment with two solutions for shuffling the products in the catalog pages.

4.) Through phpMyAdmin I did a simple query to give me all products in random order:

```
SELECT  `sku` 
FROM  `catalog_product_entity` 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY RAND( )
```

and exported the result to csv. I simply used excel to number the items from 1-60,000, creating an import csv file with columns: **sku**, **random_order** (price type), **random_order_1** (text type), with both attributes having same integer values.

5.) I used standard import method (**replace existing complex data**) in admin, 20k products at a time. After import, values for previously set and seemingly totally unrelated "**random_order**" have been deleted.

Before reindexing, every item's **sort_order** is now reset to default (=1), but it still appears in proper order on the frontend (so value still exists in product flat table), while the **random_order** and **random_order_1** attributes have their imported values.

After reindex, all trace of **sort_order** is wiped out. That would make sense if I was actually importing that attribute, but I'm not. No other attribute appears to have been affected.

I restored db from mysqldump, tried whole process again. Same result.

Comment: You said you are adding attribute values, then doing an import.  Does your import file contain the products you assigned these attribute values to?  Is the the `product/attribute` relationship that is being erased, or the `attribute/options` relationship?

Comment: Hi @Axel. I added to my question. Import file is very simple. Only SKU and the 2 NEW attributes. After running it, all those values appear to be successfully imported (visible in admin). But the unrelated attribute "sort_order" is reset to default (=1). The products still have the attribute, just at default value. So it is the attribute/options relationship that si being reset, it appears. Note it is a text attribute, not dropdown or multiselect, that is being reset to default.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe the `replace existing complex data` option removes all existing data from each product, then replaces it with the data in the CSV.  Since your `sort_order` attribute isn't present, it's just getting wiped.  Have you tried using a Dataflow product profile instead?  It might behave differently from the standard import.  You can also try Magmi which is a free open-source Magento importer that handles mass product imports/updates very well.  You can check it out here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki

Comment: That's the thing, it does not wipe other data. It seems to wipe only what was recently (or ever?) imported through the admin. Data improted earlier was not wiped. I keep hearing about weird problems with data imported by Magmi, anp Perhaps coincidentally, (I think) most data was imported using Magmi. I just don't understand why data saved by any method would be volatile like this.

Comment: I actually found the problem and fixed it some time ago. I should probably post my own answer. It was a bug in Magento's import process, having to do with a loop variable not being set/reset properly.